# Проблема с переводом в описании причины отклонения описания метки при проверке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Проблема с переводом в описании причины отклонения описания метки [при проверке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/228866).

> [image]

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external
>   source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy
>   do not provide useful guidance; try creating something useful to this
>   community specifically, and be sure to attribute the original author.
>   See: How to reference material written by others.

перевод:

> Это редактирование копирует значительное количество контента из
>   внешнего источника. Общие описания, такие как статьи из энциклопедии и
>   копии объявления не обеспечивают полезное руководство; попробуйте создать
>   что-то полезное для этого сообщества и не забудьте указать автора оригинала.
>   Смотреть: Как ссылаться на материал, написанный другими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо! Добавил перевод

> В правке содержится значительное количество содержимого из внешнего источника. Общие описания, такие как статьи из энциклопедий или текст объявлений не предоставляют полезного руководства; попробуйте создать что-то полезное именно для этого сообщества, не забыв указать источник. Обратите внимание на: Как ссылаться на материал, написанный другими.